# HTML Link to Microsoft Teams Organization Tab

Tags: html, microsoft-teams, spfx

Is there a way to link directly to the Teams "Organization" tab so a user can quickly get to the org chart?

The following code takes a user to the "Chat" tab: `<a href="IM:sip:username@domain.com">Link to Teams Chat</a>`

This is the tab I'm talking about: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-organization-tab-in-teams-ff02568b-290a-46d6-ae7a-cda22f723894

I couldn't find anything relevant here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes

Comment: This is just a tab. There is no direct way that could get you this hierarchy.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?